# Не работает ограничение по нескольким столбцам Postgresql если один из столбцов NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
-- CREATE TABLE "exports" --------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE "public"."exports" ( 
    "period" Date,
    "target_id" Integer NOT NULL,
    "segment_id" Integer NOT NULL,
    "created" Timestamp With Time Zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "unique_period" UNIQUE( "target_id", "segment_id", "period" ) );
 ;
-- -------------------------------------------------------------

insert into exports (target_id, segment_id, period) values (1, 1, NULL) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_period
DO UPDATE SET created = now();

insert into exports (target_id, segment_id, period) values (1, 1, now()::date) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_period
DO UPDATE SET created = now();

insert into exports (target_id, segment_id, period) values (1, 1, now()::date) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_period
DO UPDATE SET created = now();

insert into exports (target_id, segment_id, period) values (1, 1, NULL) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_period
DO UPDATE SET created = now();

select * from exports;
```

И получаем:

```
   period   | target_id | segment_id |            created            
------------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------
 2018-11-06 |         1 |          1 | 2018-11-06 22:36:20.534693+03
            |         1 |          1 | 2018-11-06 22:42:14.244735+03
            |         1 |          1 | 2018-11-06 22:42:18.87709+03
```

Видно что ограничение не работает совсем...

period = NULL нужен для того чтоб хранить данные не привязанные к конкретному дню.

В документации:

Вообще говоря, ограничение уникальности нарушается, если в таблице оказывается несколько строк, у которых совпадают значения всех столбцов, включённых в ограничение. Однако два значения NULL при сравнении никогда не считаются равными. Это означает, что даже при наличии ограничения уникальности в таблице можно сохранить строки с дублирующимися значениями, если они содержат NULL в одном или нескольких столбцах ограничения. Это поведение соответствует стандарту SQL, но мы слышали о СУБД, которые ведут себя по-другому. Имейте в виду эту особенность, разрабатывая переносимые приложения.

Но как с этим работать?

Comment: Так а получить-то что хотите? Какое поведение? То что проиллюстрировали примером - так и должно быть.

Comment: Используйте вместо NULL что нибудь другое. Например 1970 год

Answer (score 1):

Добавил новый столбец boolean. Добавил ещё один CONSTRAINT. Сделал так что он True когда period is null.

Но заклинание на апсерт усложняется

```
    if ... then
      forday_create = forday::date;
      vnoperiod = Null;
    else
      forday_create = NULL;
      vnoperiod = True;
    end if;

    BEGIN
     insert into exports (target_id, segment_id, period, noperiod)
      values (target.id, forid, forday_create, vnoperiod) ;
     EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
     BEGIN
        UPDATE  exports  SET  created = now()

        where target_id = target.id and segment_id = forid AND (exports.period = forday_create OR exports.noperiod = vnoperiod);
     end;end;
```